# Change Gridview column width dynamically

Tags: android, gridview, android-layout

I am trying to change the size of the items within my `GridView`. Currently the items are arranged by style (GridView_words_small) in an xml:

```
numColumns: auto_fit
stetchMode: 'spacingWidth'
ColumnWidth: width of the items being added (resource).
```

Now, through a settings change, the buttonsize can be changed. However, when I `setColumnWidth()` and `invalidate()`, no items are displayed (leaving the area blank.)

Does anyone know how to properly change `gridview` column widths dynamically?

Comment: calling invalidateViews() leads to the same result.